# filemaker import and export from MySQL

Tags: mysql, filemaker

I have database in MySQL V5. I wants to import and export data to MySQL using File Maker pro 11 without creating any file.i.e. I want direct connection between File Maker and MySQL.
Please help me......

Answer (score 2):

I can highly recommend the [Open Source Databases](http://www.actualtech.com/filemaker.php) ODBC driver from [Actual Technologies](http://www.actualtech.com/). It's a Mac OS X ODBC driver that I've used it on multiple occasions to connect FileMaker to a MySQL database. With it you can create a "shadow table" that actually shows data from the MySQL database and import from a FileMaker table to a MySQL table using the standard script steps for [import](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/scripts_ref1.36.68.html) and [export](http://www.filemaker.com/11help/html/scripts_ref1.36.69.html). This is the ESS that Sam was speaking of. For the Windows equivalent, see [FileMaker's list of ODBC drivers](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6510/~/supported-odbc/jdbc-drivers-for-filemaker).

Answer (score 1):

We have a [JDBC Plugin](http://www.360works.com/jdbc-plugin/) for that. You can do a SELECT query on your MySQL DB, then loop over the returned rows and read values out. It also supports dumping the SELECT to a txt file, which you can then import.

For importing into MySQL, your best bet is to do INSERT/UPDATE queries.

Also, you might consider using [ESS](http://www.filemaker.com/products/filemaker-pro/sql.html), which is FileMaker's built-in way of talking to MySQL.